# Method to copy a file then rename it based on a text list of names

Tags: excel, powershell, batch-file, excel-2010

I have 1 firmware file (example: firmwareV27.bdnl) I need to copy and rename into 900+ files (for unique devices). I have a list of what the unique names will be (in Excel, currently) but I have no idea how to copy the original file into a directory then rename it with a name from the list and loop it until completed.

I'm using a Windows 7 PC with Excel 2010 if that helps.

Comment: Usual comments here... What have you tried? Can you show code (and resultant errors if any) that you have attempted? What kind of directory structure are you looking at? How is the data laid out in Excel? Are you familiar with porting data from Excel into PowerShell?

Comment: Is using python an option?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I can make a batch file to move the file to be renamed and rename it a static name., but I don't know how to call the names from the list. Right now, the names I need are in a single column "A". I can use a text file if that is easier. I'm only using Excel at this point to create the list of needed file names. I don't know anything about Python.

Comment: export the list as csv and import it with powershell, there are many tutorials for working with csv in powershell so you should have no problem finding documentation

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll start looking into that unless someone comes up with a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell's fun and all, but you don't need it here. In Excel:

- Move everything to column B
- In Column A, write `copy firmwarev27.bdnl` and double click the corner square to fill-down
- Select both columns, copy and paste into notepad
- Save as `makecopies.bat` file wherever the firmware is
- run it from a command prompt

It's hundreds of lines like:

```
copy firmwarev27.bdnl   name1.bdnl
copy firmwarev27.bdnl   name2.bdnl
copy firmwarev27.bdnl   name3.bdnl
copy firmwarev27.bdnl   name4.bdnl
```

but it's quick and easy and doesn't involve any programming, which seems good if you don't know any programming.

Comment: the tag battle is on i guess? :)

Comment: This gave me a workable solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that does the trick if you've got the names saved in a plain text file(one name per line).

```
Get-Content -Path filenames.txt | foreach {copy firmwareV27.bdnl $_}
```

This should work if the Powershell is in the directory with the firmware and the filenames.txt is also in the same directory. Modify paths as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got a one liner for you. All you need to do is **highlight the whole column in your excel file and copy and paste it into a text file called "filenames.txt" so there's one file per line and then save it into the same directory as your firmware file.**

Now run this either as a command or as a batch file:

```
for /F %%i IN (filenames.txt) DO copy firmwareV27.bdnl %%i
```

There ya go, hope this helps!

Comment: I did this and ran it, but saw no output.

Comment: @Shadotek no part of it prints output, are the files there though?

Comment: That's what I mean. They should have been created in the same directory, right? I didn't see anything.

Comment: @Shadotek do the names in filenames.txt include the .bdnl extension?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting, I had to reapply the other solution to 7 different firmware files to generate 1559 total. I'd like to see this method work as well so I'll keep trying to get it to work if you want to keep at it. But yes, the names in the ext file included the .bdnl extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='filenames.txt'
echo Start
while read p; do
cp default.xsh ./new_sessions/$p.xsh
done < $filename
```

1. put the list that you want to rename with in filenames.txt
2. replace default.xsh with the name of the firmware file and put it in the same directory with filenames.txt
3. new_sessions is the name of the directory I am putting the renamed copies in.**